# Merge tex files with same layout and form

Tags: subfiles

I need your help. I am trying to prepare my template to write my thesis and I have 2 TeX files provided by the university. I couldn't merge them (I used \include, \input and subfiles). 
The best I have is that when I compile, they both appears on the same page :/

Could you help me out with this please? You can download theme [here](https://share.universite-paris-saclay.fr/index.php/s/6RO7lcKmDqYFmWI)

I use Overleaf to edit my files online.
I copy the code below if you prefer:
1ere.tex

```
`%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Modèle pour la 1ère de couverture des thèses préparées à l'Université Paris-Saclay, basé sur le modèle produit par Guillaume BRIGOT / Template for back cover of thesis made at Université Paris-Saclay, based on the template made by Guillaume BRIGOT
%%% Mis à jour par Aurélien ARNOUX (École polytechnique)/ Updated by Aurélien ARNOUX (École polytechnique)
%%% Les instructions concernant chaque donnée à remplir sont données en bloc de commentaire / Rules to fill this file are given in comment blocks
%%% ATTENTION Ces informations doivent tenir sur une seule page une fois compilées / WARNING These informations must contain in no more than one page once compiled
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Version du 23 mai 2019 (Merci à Thibault CHEVALÉRIAS (CEA) pour ses suggestions et corrections)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=16mm,
    top=30mm,
    right=16mm,
    bottom=30mm
}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bordeau}{rgb}{0.3515625,0,0.234375}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
\setlength\columnsep{10pt}
\usepackage[french]{babel}


\label{form}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Formulaire / Form
%%% Remplacer les paramètres des \newcommand par les informations demandées / Replace \newcommand parameters by asked informations
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\newcommand{\PhDTitle}{Titre de la thèse (sur plusieurs lignes si nécessaire, 4 voire 5)}   %% Titre de la thèse / Thesis title
\newcommand{\PhDname}{Prénom Nom}                                                           %% Civilité, nom et prénom /  Civility, first name and name 
\newcommand{\NNT}{20XXSACLXXXX}                                                             %% Numéro National de Thèse (donnée par la bibliothèque à la suite du 1er dépôt)/ National Thesis Number (given by the Library after the first deposit)

\newcommand{\ecodoctitle}{Dénomination}                                                     %% Nom de l'ED. Voir site de l'Université Paris-Saclay / Full name of Doctoral School. See Université Paris-Saclay website
\newcommand{\ecodocacro}{Sigle}                                                             %% Sigle de l'ED. Voir site de l'Université Paris-Saclay / Acronym of the Doctoral School. See Université Paris-Saclay website
\newcommand{\ecodocnum}{000}                                                                %% Numéro de l'école doctorale / Doctoral School number
\newcommand{\PhDspeciality}{voir spécialités par l'ED}                                      %% Spécialité de doctorat / Speciality 
\newcommand{\PhDworkingplace}{Nom de l'établissement}                                       %% Établissement de préparation / PhD working place : l'Université Paris-Sud, l'Université de Versailles-Saint-Quentin-en-Yvelines, l'Université d'Evry-Val-d'Essonne, l'Institut des sciences et industries du vivant et de l'environnement (AgroParisTech), CentraleSupélec,l'Ecole normale supérieure de Cachan, l'Ecole Polytechnique, l'Ecole nationale supérieure de techniques avancées, l'Ecole nationale de la statistique et de l’administration économique, HEC Paris, l'Institut d'optique théorique et appliquée, Télécom ParisTech, Télécom SudParis   
\newcommand{\defenseplace}{Ville de soutenance}                                             %% Ville de soutenance / Place of defense
\newcommand{\defensedate}{Date}                                                             %% Date de soutenance / Date of defense

%%% Établissement / Institution
%%% Si la thèse a été produite dans le cadre d'une co-tutelle, commenter la partie "Pas de co-tutelle" et décommenter la partie "Co-tutelle" / If the thesis has been prepared in guardianship, comment the part "Pas de co-tutelle" and uncomment the part "Co-tutelle"

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% Pas de co-tutelle %%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\logoEtt}{blank}                                                                %% NE PAS MODIFIER / DO NOT MODIFY
\newcommand{\vpostt}{0.1}                                                                   %% NE PAS MODIFIER / DO NOT MODIFY
\newcommand{\hpostt}{6}                                                                     %% NE PAS MODIFIER / DO NOT MODIFY
\newcommand{\logoEt}{etab}                                                                  %% Logo de l'établissement de soutenance. Indiquer le sigle / Institution logo. Indicate the acronym : AGRO, CENTSUP, ENS, ENSAE, ENSTA, HEC, IOGS, TPT, TSP, UEVE, UPSUD, UVSQ, X 
\newcommand{\vpos}{0.1}                                                                     %% À modifier au besoin pour aligner le logo verticalement / If needed, modify to align logo vertilcally
\newcommand{\hpos}{11}                                                                      %% À modifier au besoin pour aligner le logo horizontalement / If needed, modify to align logo horizontaly

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %%% Co-tutelle %%%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\newcommand{\logoEt}{etab}                                                                 %% Logo de l'université partenaire. Placer le fichier .png dans le répertoire '/media/etab' et indiquer le nom du fichier sans l'extension / Logo of partner university. Place the .png file in the directory '/media/etab' and point the file name without the extension
%\newcommand{\vpos}{0.1}                                                                    %% À modifier au besoin pour aligner les logos verticalement / If needed, modify to align logos vertilcally
%\newcommand{\hpos}{11}                                                                     %% À modifier au besoin pour aligner les logos horizontalement / If needed, modify to align logos horizontaly
%\newcommand{\logoEtt}{etab2}                                                               %% Logo de l'établissement de soutenance. Le nom du fichier correspond au sigle de l'établissement /  Institution logo. Filename correspond to institution acronym : AGRO, CENTSUP, ENS, ENSAE, ENSTA, HEC, IOGS, TPT, TSP, UEVE, UPSUD, UVSQ, X 
%\newcommand{\vpostt}{0.1}                                                                  %% À modifier au besoin pour aligner les logos verticalement / If needed, modify to align logos vertilcally
%\newcommand{\hpostt}{6}                                                                    %% À modifier au besoin pour aligner les logos horizontalement / If needed, modify to align logos horizontaly


%%% JURY

% Lors du premier dépôt de la thèse le nom du président nest pas connu, le choix du président se fait par les membres du Jury juste avant la soutenance. La précision est apportée sur la couverture lors du second dépôt / Choice of the jury's president is made during the defense. Thus, it must be specified only for the second file deposition in ADUM.
% Tous les membres du juty listés doivent avoir été présents lors de la soutenance / All the jury members listed here must have been present during the defense.

%%% Membre n°1 (Président) / Member n°1 (President)
\newcommand{\jurynameA}{Prénom Nom}
\newcommand{\juryadressA}{Statut, Établissement (Unité de recherche)}
\newcommand{\juryroleA}{Président}

%%% Membre n°2 (Rapporteur) / Member n°2 (Reviewer)
\newcommand{\jurynameB}{Prénom Nom}
\newcommand{\juryadressB}{Statut, Établissement (Unité de recherche)}
\newcommand{\juryroleB}{Rapporteur}

%%% Membre n°3 (Rapporteur) / Member n°3 (Reviewer)
\newcommand{\jurynameC}{Prénom Nom}
\newcommand{\juryadressC}{Statut, Établissement (Unité de recherche)}
\newcommand{\juryroleC}{Rapporteur}

%%% Membre n°4 (Examinateur) / Member n°4 (Examiner)
\newcommand{\jurynameD}{Prénom Nom}
\newcommand{\juryadressD}{Statut, Établissement (Unité de recherche)}
\newcommand{\juryroleD}{Examinateur}

%%% Membre n°5 (Directeur de thèse) / Member n°5 (Thesis supervisor)
\newcommand{\jurynameE}{Prénom Nom}
\newcommand{\juryadressE}{Statut, Établissement (Unité de recherche)}
\newcommand{\juryroleE}{Directeur de thèse}

%%% Membre n°6 (Co-directeur de thèse) / Member n°6 (Thesis co-supervisor)
\newcommand{\jurynameF}{Prénom Nom}
\newcommand{\juryadressF}{Statut, Établissement (Unité de recherche)}
\newcommand{\juryroleF}{Co-directeur de thèse}

%%% Membre n°7 (Invité) / Member n°7 (Guest)
\newcommand{\jurynameG}{Prénom Nom}
\newcommand{\juryadressG}{Statut, Établissement (Unité de recherche)}
\newcommand{\juryroleG}{Invité}

%%% Membre n°8 (Invité) / Member n°8 (Guest)
\newcommand{\jurynameH}{Prénom Nom}
\newcommand{\juryadressH}{Statut, Établissement (Unité de recherche)}
\newcommand{\juryroleH}{Invité}

%% Il est possible d'ajouter des membres supplémentaires selon le même modèle / More jury members can be added according to the same model

\label{layout}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Mise en page / Page layout      
%%% NE RIEN MODIFIER EXCEPTÉ LA PARTIE CONCERNANT LE JURY (voir \label{jury}) SI BESOIN / DO NOT MODIFY EXCEPT SECTION CONCERNING JURY (see \label{jury}) IF NEEDED
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Méta-données du PDF / PDF meta-datas
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={\PhDname},
    pdfsubject={Manuscrit de thèse de doctorat},
    pdftitle={\PhDTitle},
}

\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty}

%\color{bordeau} \hfill \vfill \tiny \ecodocnum
\begin{textblock}{5}(0,0)
    \textblockcolour{bordeau}
    %\vspace{10mm}
    \includegraphics [scale=1]{media/bande.png}
    \vspace{300mm}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{1}(0.6,9.5)

    \Huge{\rotatebox{90}{\color{white}{\fontsize{38}{54}\selectfont Thèse de doctorat}}}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{1}(0.6,3)
    \Large{\rotatebox{90}{\color{white}{NNT : \NNT}}}
\end{textblock}




\begin{textblock}{1}(\hpostt,\vpostt)
    \textblockcolour{white}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{media/etab/\logoEtt.png}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{1}(\hpos,\vpos)
    \textblockcolour{white}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{media/etab/\logoEt.png}   
\end{textblock}

%\vspace{6cm}
%% Texte
\begin{textblock}{10}(5.7,3)
    \textblockcolour{white}

    \color{bordeau}
    %\begin{center}  
    \begin{flushright}
        \huge{\PhDTitle} \bigskip %% Titre de la thèse 
        \vfill
        \color{black} %% Couleur noire du reste du texte
        \normalsize {Thèse de doctorat de l'Université Paris-Saclay} \\
        préparée à \PhDworkingplace \\ \bigskip
        \vfill
        École doctorale n$^{\circ}$\ecodocnum ~\ecodoctitle ~(\ecodocacro)  \\

        \small{Spécialité de doctorat: \PhDspeciality} \bigskip %% Spécialité 
        \vfill  
        \footnotesize{Thèse présentée et soutenue à \defenseplace, le \defensedate, par} \bigskip
        \vfill
        \Large{\textbf{\textsc{\PhDname}}} %% Nom du docteur
        \vfill
        %\bigskip
    \end{flushright}

    %\end{center}
    \color{black}
    %% Jury
    \begin{flushleft}

        \small Composition du Jury :
    \end{flushleft}
    %% Members of the jury

    \small
    %\begin{center}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}lm{#1}}

    \label{jury}                                                                                %% Mettre à jour si des membres ont été ajoutés ou retirés / Update if members have been added or removed
    \begin{flushleft}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} L{9.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
        \jurynameA  \\ \juryadressA & \juryroleA \\[5pt]
        \jurynameB  \\ \juryadressB & \juryroleB \\[5pt]
        \jurynameC  \\ \juryadressC & \juryroleC \\[5pt]
        \jurynameD  \\ \juryadressD & \juryroleD \\[5pt]
        \jurynameE  \\ \juryadressE & \juryroleE \\[5pt]
        \jurynameF  \\ \juryadressF & \juryroleF \\[5pt]
        \jurynameG  \\ \juryadressG & \juryroleG \\[5pt]
        \jurynameH  \\ \juryadressH & \juryroleH \\[5pt]
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{flushleft}   
    %\end{center}
\end{textblock}

\end{document}`
```

And the second: 4eme.tex

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Modèle pour la 4ème de couverture des thèses préparées à l'Université Paris-Saclay, basé sur le modèle produit par Nikolas STOTT / Template for back cover of thesis made at Université Paris-Saclay, based on the template made by Nikolas STOTT
%%% Mis à jour par Aurélien ARNOUX (École polytechnique)/ Updated by Aurélien ARNOUX (École polytechnique)
%%% Les instructions concernant chaque donnée à remplir sont données en bloc de commentaire / Rules to fill this file are given in comment blocks
%%% ATTENTION Ces informations doivent tenir sur une seule page une fois compilées / WARNING These informations must contain in no more than one page once compiled
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Version du 23 mai 2019 (Merci à Thibault CHEVALÉRIAS (CEA) pour ses suggestions et corrections)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
left=16mm,
top=30mm,
right=16mm,
bottom=30mm
}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bordeau}{rgb}{0.3515625,0,0.234375}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
\setlength\columnsep{10pt}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\label{form}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Formulaire / Form
%%% Remplacer les paramètres des \newcommand par les informations demandées / Replace \newcommand parameters by asked informations
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\logoEd}{ed}                                                                        %% Logo de l'école doctorale. Indiquer le sigle / Doctoral school logo. Indicate the acronym : 2MIB; AAIF; ABIES; BIOSIGNE; CBMS; EDMH; EDOM; EDPIF; EDSP; EOBE; INTERFACES; ITFA; PHENIICS; SDSV; SDV; SHS; SMEMAG; SSMMH; STIC
\newcommand{\PhDTitleFR}{titre (en français)}                                                   %% Titre de la thèse en français / Thesis title in french
\newcommand{\keywordsFR}{3 à 6 mots clés}                                                       %% Mots clés en français, séprarés par des , / Keywords in french, separated by ,
\newcommand{\abstractFR}{\lipsum[1-3]}                                                          %% Résumé en français / abstract in french

\newcommand{\PhDTitleEN}{titre (en anglais)}                                                    %% Titre de la thèse en anglais / Thesis title in english
\newcommand{\keywordsEN}{3 à 6 mots clés}                                                       %% Mots clés en anglais, séprarés par des , / Keywords in english, separated by ,
\newcommand{\abstractEN}{\lipsum[1-3]}                                                          %% Résumé en anglais / abstract in english

\label{layout}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Mise en page / Page layout      
%%% NE RIEN MODIFIER / DO NOT MODIFY
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

%%% Logo de l'école doctorale. Le nom du fichier correspond au sigle de l'ED / Doctoral school logo. Filename correspond to doctoral school acronym
%%% Les noms valides sont / Valid names are : 2MIB; AAIF; ABIES; BIOSIGNE; CBMS; EDMH; EDOM; EDPIF; EDSP; EOBE; INTERFACES; ITFA; PHENIICS; SDSV; SDV; SHS; SMEMAG; SSMMH; STIC
\begin{textblock*}{61mm}(16mm,3mm)
    \noindent\includegraphics[height=24mm]{media/ed/\logoEd.jpeg}
\end{textblock*}



%%%Titre de la thèse en français / Thesis title in french
\begin{center}
\fcolorbox{bordeau}{white}{\parbox{0.95\textwidth}{
{\bf Titre:} \PhDTitleFR 
\medskip

%%%Mots clés en français, séprarés par des ; / Keywords in french, separated by ;
{\bf Mots clés:} \keywordsFR 
\vspace{-2mm}

%%% Résumé en français / abstract in french
\begin{multicols}{2}
{\bf Résumé:} 
\abstractFR 
\end{multicols}
}}
\end{center}

\vspace*{0mm}

%%%Titre de la thèse en anglais / Thesis title in english
\begin{center}
\fcolorbox{bordeau}{white}{\parbox{0.95\textwidth}{
{\bf Title:} \PhDTitleEN 

\medskip

%%%Mots clés en anglais, séprarés par des ; / Keywords in english, separated by ;
{\bf Keywords:}  \keywordsEN %%3 à 6 mots clés%%
\vspace{-2mm}
\begin{multicols}{2}

%%% Résumé en anglais / abstract in english
{\bf Abstract:} 
\abstractEN
\end{multicols}
}}
\end{center}


\begin{textblock*}{161mm}(10mm,270mm)
\color{bordeau}
{\bf\noindent Université Paris-Saclay            }

\noindent Espace Technologique / Immeuble Discovery 

\noindent Route de l’Orme aux Merisiers RD 128 / 91190 Saint-Aubin, France 
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{20mm}(182mm,255mm)
\includegraphics[width=20mm]{media/UPSACLAY-petit}
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

What i would like is to have a `main.tex` file with the \usepackage stuff and to separate my files into several documents. The `1ere.tex` file would be the "Coverpage", the `4eme.tex` the "abstract" so my document could look like

```
    \documentclass[something]
\usepackage{som1}
\usepackage{some2}
%etc..

\begin{document}
\include{coverpage.tex}
\include{abstract.tex}
\include{chapter1}
%etc...
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your help. This thing is turning me crazy :)

Comment: Using the "article" class for a PhD thesis looks very strange. For a PhD thesis in France, please look at: https://ctan.org/pkg/yathesis?lang=en It does everything you need plus much more.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the approach used here is far from being the best one. I have written a package that does that in a much better way.
Nevertheless, I you want to use them, you must compiles them as they are, and in your main document you will  include them by loading `pdfpages` package, and using `\includepdf{...}` at the suitable positions.